# En esta tabla, el valor de la clave documento, ¿cuál es el numero más grande que puede tener?

Tags: sql, sql-server, table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Cliente](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Apellido] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Documento] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Edad] [int] NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Telefono] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Direccion] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [EntidadID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

lo que necesito es que responda es lo que le pido en el título sobre el contenido de este mensaje de este POST

Comment: El valor que indique la documentación de la versión de SQL Server que uses para el tipo de dato int

Comment: @ssaxxzzx te sirvieron las respuestas?

Comment: si me sirvieron

Comment: @ssaxxzzx podrias marca como aceptada la respuesta que mas util te parecio, y si lo deseas puedes darle tambien un voto positivo, gracias

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de datos **int** ocupa **4 bytes** en memoria, y su intervalo va desde **-2.147.483.648** hasta **2.147.483.647**, existen otros tipo de datos numéricos tales como **bigint**, **smallint**, **tinyint**, cada uno de los cuales tiene diferentes intervalos numéricos. El tipo de dato numérico a escoger depende del contexto, por ejemplo para guardar la edad de una persona sería ineficiente usar el tipo de datos **int**, ya que la persona como máximo vive **120** años, por lo que estaríamos desperdiciando **3 bytes**, en su lugar debe usarse el tipo **tinyint**, que ocupa un intervalo de **0** a **255**, es decir **1 byte** de memoria. El tipo **int** podría usarse por ejemplo para guardar la cantidad de personas de un país, distancias entre dos regiones, es decir, valores numéricos relativamente grandes.

Answer (score -2):

El numero mas grande que puedes colocar en un `int` (entero) es `2.147.483.647`. Si deseas numeros o ID mas grandes, puedes optar por colocar un `nvarchar[max]`el cual no te limitara. Adicional, te recomiendo darle una revisada a la documentacion de [Microsoft Aqui](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/int-bigint-smallint-and-tinyint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Donde explican varias cosas a tener en cuenta como el peso de cada tipo de dato en la DB.

Comment: text es un tipo de dato, que esta obsoleto. [Tipos de datos a eliminar](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). En mi opinión, lo más lógico, es que si usas números y te parecen pequeños, utilices tipos de datos numéricos que permitan números más grandes, no tipos de texto.

Comment: @Javifer2 Gracias por la referencia a los tipos de datos a eliminar. En mi opinión crear un DB con id numérico no es lo mejor, por ende recomiendo nvarchar.

Comment: Un id de texto suele traer a gente preguntando por qué se ordena el 10 antes del 2. También es más complicado de mantener en sistemas con usuarios concurrentes.